# my grandfather invented the first automated tea bag machine

Tags: patent-infringment

Isn't there royalties insued by the inventors family if the patent is re-purchased?
     It seems The National Tea Company , not in existence, still owes my family money.

Answer (score 1):

Any patent from that time from would have long long ago expired and the time to sue anyone for infringement during the time it was in force is also long gone. A patent can be sold outright by the inventor to a company or they could agree on a royalty of some sort. That is all between the inventor and the licensee or assignee.